# Div follow mouse and avoid browser boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've figured how to get a div to follow a mouse, but how can I get it to reposition when the div comes close to the edge of the browser window?

For example, on Youtube, if you hover over the video makers name the div will *always* stay in the browser and never go off screen.

[Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf6LD2B_kDQ&index=26&list=PLDSvAKa1vkqni_pvzN-VF80aRtAowgUhE), hover over Lindsey Stirling and resize your browser a few times for a live example.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe add margin to your div?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "title" property.  This example should work fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/8vj3k7zo/

```
<div title="no, I am 100% serious, please look at me!  Oh, and try resizing the browser window.">This is some test text look at me!!!"</div>
```

Of course, you can't style the title tooltip, as it's part of the native browser implementation.  If you'd like to get a *styled* div to peek over the edge of the browser, you can't do that.

On the other hand, if you would like to make sure that the entirety of the custom CSS tooltip is always inside the browser when the mouse is close to the edge (and not partially outside the bounds of the window), check out this excellent library: https://github.com/HubSpot/tooltip